# ¿Valida si un valor ya fue ingresado, que no permita ingresar mas, jquery?

Tags: jquery

Actualmente genero un listado dinamico con jquery, el listado dinamico es formado mediante un arreglo de objetos el cual queda de esta forma:

```
var lista_productos_elegir = $('.lista_productos_elegir');
                    valCarrito = response.data;
                       $.each(valCarrito, function (i) {
                            $('<li/>').addClass('swipeout swipeout_productos1')
                                .append($('<div/>').addClass('swipeout-content item-content')
                                    .append($('<div/>').addClass('item-media')
                                        .append('<img src="' + valCarrito[i].Url + '" onerror="this.onerror=null;" alt="" width="40" height="60" />'))
                                    .append($('<div/>').addClass('item-inner')
                                        .append($('<div/>').addClass('item-title-row')
                                            .append($('<div style="font-size: 12px;"/>').addClass('item-title').append(valCarrito[i].Codigo_Inventario + " - " + valCarrito[i].Descripcion))
                                            .append('<div class="codInventario_material" style="display:none">' + valCarrito[i].Codigo_Inventario + '</div>')
                                            .append('<div class="tipo_material" style="display:none">' + valCarrito[i].Tipo + '</div>')
                                            .append('<div class="tipo_costo_material" style="display:none">' + valCarrito[i].TipoCosto + '</div>')
                                            .append('<div class="preciosocio_material" style="display:none">' + valCarrito[i].PrecioSocio + '</div>')
                                            .append('<div class="volumenNegocio_material" style="display:none">' + valCarrito[i].VolumenNegocio + '</div>')
                                            .append('<div class="cantidadProducto_material" style="display:none">' + valCarrito[i].Cantidad + '</div>')
                                            .append('<div class="item-after" data-unit-price="' + valCarrito[i].PrecioSocio + '"><span class="product-amount" style="font-size: 12px;">' + valCarrito[i].PrecioSocio + '</span></div>')
                                        )
                                        .append($('<div/>').addClass('item-text')
                                            /*.append('<input type="number" class="add_material_impreso" value="0" min="0" placeholder="Ingrese cantidad">')*/
                                              .append($('<div/>').addClass('chip chip-small').append('<div class="chip-label"><span class="product-quantity">' + valCarrito[i].Cantidad + '</span></div>'))
                                              .append($('<div style="background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);"/>').addClass('chip chip-small').append('<div class="chip-label"><button class="sumarProducto1">+</button></div>'))
                                              .append($('<div style="background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);"/>').addClass('chip chip-small').append('<div class="chip-label"><button class="restarProducto1">-</button></div>')) 
                                        )
                                    )
                                )
                                .appendTo(lista_productos_elegir);
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

para tal situacion voy incrementando el valor de la cantidad con esta función, como podran ver Producto 1, producto 2 y producto 3 tiene cantidad 1, que se si es mayor a uno ya no debe permitir:

```
$$('.lista_productos_elegir').on('click','.sumarProducto1', function(e){
        var list                          = $(this).closest('.swipeout_productos1');
        var el_product_quantity_producto1 = list.find('.product-quantity');
        var tipo_material                 = list.find('.tipo_material').text();
        var tipo_costo_material           = list.find('.tipo_costo_material').text();
        var codinv_material               = list.find('.codInventario_material').text();
        var preciosocio_material          = list.find('.preciosocio_material').text();
        var volumenNegocio_material       = list.find('.volumenNegocio_material').text();
            product_sum                   = parseInt(el_product_quantity_producto1.text());
            cantidad_suma                 = product_sum+1;
            el_product_quantity_producto1.text(cantidad_suma);
            if (cantidad_suma > 1){
                myApp.alert("Puede llevar un máximo de 1 productos");
                product_sum = 1;
                el_product_quantity_producto1.text(product_sum);
            }
    });
```

El detalle es que unicamente en ese listado tengo permito incrementar cualquierda de esos productos a el valor cantidad 1, es decir que si el producto 1 ya tiene el 1, en los demas registros como Producto 1,2,3 y 4 ya no me debe permitir incrementar, hasta que le reste al Producto que ya tenga asignado 1.

De antemano muy agradecido.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No puedo hacer comentarios, pero espero haber entendido:
Tienes varias opciones. Veo que el input de cantidad tiene una clase con nombre "product-quantity", y este campo se genera por cada producto, así que puedes obtener todas esos input así:

```
var cantidadInputs = $(".product-quantity")
```

Declara un flag para validar si ya existe un valor en algun input que sea igual a 1:

```
var existeValor = false;
```

Esto te retorna todo los tag con esa clase en un array, en este caso todos los input de cantidad. ahora haces un for recorriendo "cantidadInputs".

```
for(var i=0; i<$cantidadInputs.length;i++){
  //haces la lógica validando cada registro
  if(Number($cantidadInputs[i].value)>=1){
    //Cambias a true el flag y rompes el for
    existeValor = true;
    break;
  }
}
```

Por último validas si existe valor es igual a true, si es así, botas el mensaje que no se puede si no, haces el flujo que desees.

Hay muchas opciones, esa se me ocurrió ahorita. Espero haberte ayudado.

```
if(existeValor){
  // mensaje que no se puede aumentar otro item
}else{
  //Permites aumentar el otro item.
}
```